# How to navigate to the next result in "tiny search" IntelliJ 2016

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-16

In IntelliJ I can usually search in any Window (not being an editor) by just start typing. Is there any way to navigate through the results?

[image: as an example: searching in database tables]

as an example: searching in database tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up and down arrows usually work for this.